# apply family functions doesnt work with group_by() but it does with select()

Tags: r, tidyverse, lapply

I am new in R and facing strange issues.

I am trying to create multiple plots for each character variable against count of exited var.

**df_churn**

```
gender  geography exited
<chr>   <chr>     <fctr>

Female  France  Churn       
Female  Spain   Remain      
Female  France  Churn       
Female  France  Remain      
Female  Spain   Remain      
Male    Spain   Churn       
Male    France  Remain      
Female  Germany Churn       
Male    France  Remain      
Male    France  Remain
```

I am getting an error with `group_by()` even before I start plotting within `lapply()`

```
  lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
    df_churn %>% 
      group_by(feature, exited) %>%
      count()
  })
```

where as if use `select()` instead of `group_by()` then it works:

```
  lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
    df_churn %>% 
      select(feature, exited) %>% 
      head()
  })

#------------------output-------------#
geography exited
<chr>     <fctr>

France  Churn           
Spain   Remain          
France  Churn           
France  Remain          
Spain   Remain          
Spain   Churn


gender exited
<chr>  <fctr>

Female  Churn           
Female  Remain          
Female  Churn           
Female  Remain          
Female  Remain          
Male    Churn
```

**How can I fix this for group_by() ?**

I am not able to understand `apply` family workings and `enquous`, `rlang`/ `functional programming` in r which should make repetitive work easier. Instead all of this sometimes makes it really frustrating,

Will also appreciate any good source of learning links for them as well.

thanks!!

Comment: Avoid the mix of packages with different grammar and semantics. Because `lapply` is part of `base` R, use the synonymous version of `group_by`: `aggregate`.

Comment: yes, that's a good advice. I will keep this in mind from now on, thanks !!

Comment: @Parfait but `tally`, `count` are not working with `aggregate()`.

this code fails: 
```{r}
df_churn %>% aggregate(by = list(geography, gender, exited), FUN = count)


```

but this code works: 

```{r}
df_churn %>% aggregate(by = list(geography, gender, exited), FUN = mean)
```

Comment: There is no `count` in base R. Use `length` and you need to pass args as strings. See how to build formula in `aggregate`: https://rextester.com/EQBR29621. Welcome to [tinyverse](http://www.tinyverse.org/)!

Comment: thanks @Parfait for sharing the demo code .. this was really helpful!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your code works with `select` and not with `group_by` is because `select` works with character values but not `group_by`.

1. To fix this use `sym` with `!!` :

```
library(dplyr)

lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
  df_churn %>% 
    group_by(!!sym(feature), exited) %>%
    count()
})
```

2. with `.data` :

```
lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
  df_churn %>% 
    group_by(.data[[feature]], exited) %>%
    count()
})
```

3. With `across` :

```
lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
  df_churn %>% 
    group_by(across(c(feature, "exited"))) %>%
    count()
})
```

4. With `get` :

```
lapply(c("geography","gender"), FUN = function(feature){
  df_churn %>% 
    group_by(get(feature), exited) %>%
    count()
})
```

Comment: you can also try with `group_by_at(c(feature, 'exited'))`

Comment: Yes but `group_by_at` is superseded now so we now have to use this with `across`.

Comment: then with `group_by(across(c(feature, exited)))` and it handles on its own chars and names

Comment: thanks @RonakShah it worked well and will use this only.

Comment: if `count` is the actual purpose and not just a reproducible example, you can go with `lapply(c("geography","gender"), function(feature) count(df_churn, across(c(feature, exited))))`